# Spring Boot Actuator metrics mem and mem.free

Tags: java, spring-boot

What is the meaning of **mem** and **mem.free** in Spring Boot metrics exposed via **/metrics** endpoint?

We are load testing a new Spring Boot microservice deployed in three nodes, **mem** for each box is always around 250M out of 4G total in VM, **mem.free** under unrealistic load like 100 times of normal load can go down to 15M and slowly recovers after the test.

They are not heap memory because Spring Boot Metrics report them separately and they are not Java process itself because from command line I can see no matter how big the load, it stays at 16% of 4G which is about 900MB. Here is /metrics call response snippet:

```
{
    mem: 227657,
    mem.free: 44280,
    processors: 2,
    instance.uptime: 80393579,
    uptime: 80414405,
    systemload.average: 0.03,
    heap.committed: 133632,
    heap.init: 61440,
    heap.used: 89351,
    heap: 872448,
    nonheap.committed: 96688,
    nonheap.init: 2496,
    nonheap.used: 94025,
    nonheap: 0,
    threads.peak: 109,
    threads.daemon: 34,
    threads.totalStarted: 183,
    threads: 63,
    classes: 10079,
    classes.loaded: 10155,
    classes.unloaded: 76,
```

....
}

Grafana **mem.free** screenshot for last 24 hours, the lowest point is during that heavy load testing (15MB!)
[image]

Grafana cpu and memory usage report is shown below which tells me CPU under stressed during that period which is understandable. However Java process memory (only 1 Spring boot running in that box) is stable:
[image]

So again what is the meaning of **mem** and **mem.free** in Spring Boot metrics?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`mem` is the total amount of memory that the JVM is currently using. It is the sum of two values:

- [`Runtime.totalMemory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory--)
- The value of `getUsed()` from [`MemoryMXBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html#getNonHeapMemoryUsage--)

`mem.free` is the amount of memory that's available to the JVM. It's a single value:

- [`Runtime.freeMemory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html)

To see more of the details, take a look at Spring Boot's [`SystemPublicMetrics`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/SystemPublicMetrics.java) class.

Comment: Thanks. It is very clear explanation. Now I can see mem(227657) = 
    mem.free(44280) + heap.used(89351) + nonheap.used(94025)

Comment: I also find in those boxes the default JVM InitialHeapSize=31457280 which is so tiny and not even enough for the classes (94025000). When I set -Xms=256m, mem becomes 321136 and mem.free increases to 169665 which is nice.

Comment: What is essential to add is that (contrary to the JVM) the actuator reports those numbers in KB rather than bytes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/SystemPublicMetrics.java#L136