# Spring boot 2 actuator metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

Is there any reference detailed documentation of spring boot 2 metrics.

I mean

```
{
  "names": [
    "jvm.memory.max",
    "http.server.requests",
    "process.files.max",
    "jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
    "tomcat.cache.hit",
    "rabbitmq.channels",
    "system.load.average.1m",
    "tomcat.cache.access",
    "jvm.memory.used",
    "jvm.gc.max.data.size",
    "jdbc.connections.max",
    "jdbc.connections.min",
    "jvm.gc.pause",
    "jvm.memory.committed",
    "system.cpu.count",
    "logback.events",
    "rabbitmq.connections",
    "tomcat.global.sent",
    "jvm.buffer.memory.used",
    "tomcat.sessions.created",
    "jvm.threads.daemon",
    "system.cpu.usage",
    "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
    "tomcat.global.request.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.idle",
    "hikaricp.connections.pending",
    "tomcat.global.request",
    "rabbitmq.rejected",
    "tomcat.sessions.expired",
    "hikaricp.connections",
    "jvm.threads.live",
    "jvm.threads.peak",
    "tomcat.global.received",
    "hikaricp.connections.active",
    "hikaricp.connections.creation",
    "process.uptime",
    "tomcat.sessions.rejected",
    "process.cpu.usage",
    "tomcat.threads.config.max",
    "jvm.classes.loaded",
    "hikaricp.connections.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.min",
    "rabbitmq.consumed",
    "jvm.classes.unloaded",
    "tomcat.global.error",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.current",
    "tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
    "jvm.gc.live.data.size",
    "tomcat.servlet.request.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.usage",
    "tomcat.threads.current",
    "tomcat.servlet.request",
    "hikaricp.connections.timeout",
    "process.files.open",
    "jvm.buffer.count",
    "jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.acquire",
    "tomcat.threads.busy",
    "rabbitmq.published",
    "process.start.time",
    "tomcat.servlet.error",
    "rabbitmq.acknowledged"
  ]
}
```

- Which metrics should I use for memory / gc / cpu usage. Also what does the values represent.
- Also in spring boot 1.5.x, i can simply get used heap, committed heap, gc count etc. How can i get those values?

Also is there a way I can get all metrics at one call. I mean to get all metrics i need to call many hits rite now in boot 2.

Answer (score 13):

Still learning how to use Spring's new dimensional implementation myself, but I think I can help you out with some of your question. As you found, the metrics are much richer in Spring Boot 2 than Spring Boot 1.5.

There's a good blog post on Spring's site that goes into detail what the new metric engine gives you and why they though the change was needed: [Micrometer: Spring Boot 2's new application metrics collector](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector)

> A. Which metrics should I use for memory / gc / cpu usage. Also what does the values represent.

When you navigate to your application's `actuator/metric` endpoint you can view your suitable metrics.

#### Memory

- `jvm.memory.max`
- `jvm.memory.used`
- `jvm.gc.memory.promoted`
- `jvm.memory.committed`
- `jvm.buffer.memory.used`
- `jvm.gc.memory.allocated`

#### GC

- `jvm.gc.memory.allocated`
- `jvm.gc.memory.promoted`

#### CPU

- `system.cpu.usage`
- `system.cpu.count`
- `process.cpu.usage`

> B. Also in spring boot 1.5.x, i can simply get used heap, committed heap, gc count etc. How can i get those values?

As you mentioned, you'll have to view your metrics by dimension.

For example, in Spring Boot <2, in order to view the `heap.committed:120000`, you'd have to just make a GET request on `/actuator/metrics`.

In Spring Boot 2, to return the metric for **TOTAL** committed memory (heap and nonheap) you'll make a GET request on `/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.committed`.

You'll get a response similar to:

```
{
    "name": "jvm.memory.committed",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "VALUE",
            "value": 240000
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "area",
            "values": [
                "heap",
                "nonheap"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "id",
            "values": [
                "Compressed Class Space",
                "PS Survivor Space",
                "PS Old Gen",
                "Metaspace",
                "PS Eden Space",
                "Code Cache"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To only view the committed heap value, make a GET request using the heap tag: `/acutator/metrics/jvm.memory.committted?tag=area:heap`. You should see something similar to:

```
{
    "name": "jvm.memory.committed",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "VALUE",
            "value": 120000
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "id",
            "values": [
                "PS Eden Space",
                "PS Survivor Space",
                "PS Old Gen"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Spring Boot's [Metrics Reference Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html) are a great resource and how I learned about the tag syntax (it's the last section).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354693/spring-boot-actuator-metrics-mem-and-mem-free): Take a look at how previous versions mapped to the old metrics in Spring Boot's [SystemPublicMetrics.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/SystemPublicMetrics.java) class if you'd like to ensure that these metrics are mapping correctly to your application's previous metrics.

> Also is there a way I can get all metrics at one call. I mean to get all metrics i need to call many hits rite now in boot 2.

I don't think there is at this time through the metrics endpoint out of the box. Of interest to you may be Micrometer's [`HierarchicalNameMapper.java`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/util/HierarchicalNameMapper.java) class. Per, [Micrometer's Docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts):

> > Dimensionality. Whether the system supports metric names to be enriched with tag key/value pairs. If a system is not dimensional, it is hierarchical, which means it only supports a flat metric name. When publishing metrics to hierarchical systems, Micrometer flattens the set of tag/key value pairs and adds them to the name.

So, if you publish your data to a hierarchical system (such as JMX) your metrics will be flattened. You could also implement your own flattening mapper if you're exporting to another system.

Comment: what a beautiful answer!